# SD Card - Corrupted Files

Tags: sd-card, micro-sd-card

Most of my files of various types on my SD card got corrupted, and other files with weird names appeared. So what should I do? Is it safe to delete these files?

[image: An example of the files]

Comment: And you need the data back? If not try formatting the card rather than deleting the files. Most likely the file system is corrupt and format will create a new file system.

Comment: You can delete them, they may go away, but you should be more concerned about why they appeared. It could be malware, but that isn't very likely. The more likely cause is that the SD card is failing. Recover what you can and format the drive, if you are able. Even if it works after formatting I would not trust it. SD cards are not intended for long-term reliable data storage, and once they fail, they are probably dead.

Answer (score 0):

The picture does not convey much information.

However if the Card was corrupted, delete what you can. If there is anything you can transfer to your computer do that.

Then format the card and restore any files you can.

If there are errors formatting the card, then simply replace it.

Remember to do an orderly disconnect (Windows has a disconnect icon) before removing the card.

Comment: Always "Eject" ("unmount" on Linux:en) when handling removable media, if you're not doing that you will eventually have similar mishaps appear. Also be aware that Flash media wears out, and in the best case that gets detected - leaving it in "read only" state.